# How can I convert a string which is a in encoding in byte to a previous string value?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a file inside there is this **dGVzdA==**, **dGVzdA==** is the word **test** convert in byte[].

After that I want to get this word to have my string **test** again So I do this :

```
[HttpPost("[Action]")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ExtractLicenseData(IFormFile file){
    string fileContents ;

    using (var stream = file.OpenReadStream())
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            fileContents = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        }
    }
    string test = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(fileContents); // error
    return BadRequest(test);
}
```

But when I try to do `string test = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(fileContents);` I have the error :

> cannot convert from 'string' to 'byte[]'

To resume :

I have my string **dGVzdA==** I want to finally convert it in my original string **test**.

/!\ To go from **test** to **dGVzdA==** I do this `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("test")`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> dGVzdA== is the word test convert in byte[].

No, `dGVzdA==` is the base64-encoded representation of the bytes 0x74, 0x65, 0x73, 0x74... which is in turn the ASCII-encoded representation of the text "test".

So if you want a byte array with content 0x74, 0x65, 0x73, 0x74, you need to just perform base64 decoding:

```
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(fileContents);
```

If you then want to get back to the string by applying the ASCII encoding, you'd use:

```
string text = Encoding.GetString(bytes);
```

But if the file content is definitely going to be ASCII text anyway, it would be better if you could avoid the base64 part in the first place. It's not clear where that's come from.

> To go from `test` to `dGVzdA==` I do this `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("test")`.

No, you don't. `Encoding.ASCII.GetByte("test")` returns you a byte array with the bytes 0x74, 0x65, 0x73, 0x74, whereas `dGVzdA==` is the result of converting that byte array into a string via base64 encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is already a `string`, `reader.ReadToEndAsync()` will read whole file till the end and return it in a `string`.

You don't need to do `Encoding.ASCII.GetString(fileContents);`, check `fileContents` after:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    fileContents = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    // here
}
```

now do `Convert.FromBase64String(fileContents);` there you will have you bytes than get your String from bytes.